# Hive digits after decimal

Tags: hive, decimal, precision

Over hive below is the response of query:
select 0.04376134693382716 * 29; 
**Result**: 1.2690790610809877

Over oracle below is the response: 
select 0.04376134693382716 * 29 from dual; 
**Result**:1.26907906108098764

Question: In hive its rounding off after decimal 16 digits. However in oracle its throwing correct result. Can someone help to provide the solution to get the same result in hive as coming in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it to a decimal in hive. Example: `select cast(value as decimal)` with precision.

Comment: Great...it worked. Thank Gaurav for quick response. Appreciate your response.